# How to compute the value of an indicator on a larger timeframe when on a smaller timeframe

Tags: pine-script

If I have to access the daily closing value of the previous day in the current intraday, then I simply use the security function with close[1] as described in the following https://getsatisfaction.com/tradingview/topics/using-pine-script-to-retrieve-previous-days-close-from-within-intraday-chart.

However, it is not clear to me if I use the same concept within the calculation of indicator. 
There is some mention of this in the discussion of the look ahead parameter at [https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Context_Switching,*The*%E2%80%98security%E2%80%99_Function](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Context_Switching,_The_%E2%80%98security%E2%80%99_Function), but I'm not fully confident about my understanding..

Can people please look at this code snippet

In this example, the ADX indicator is calculated on the daily value and then accessed on a 30 minute time frame and the next day. If the ADX is more than 25 and it is bullish, we entered into a long position. If the ADX is less than 25 or it is bearish, we close the position.

As a concrete example, the intention is the following: on a Tuesday morning at the end of the first 30 minutes of trading, we will look at the ADX that is constructed on the end of day closing value Monday evening.

To achieve this, I have simply replaced the references to high and low in the function to calculate the ADX by high[1] and low[1].

Please advise if this code is the recommended way of achieving that or if there are any possible bugs.

Thank you

```
//@version=3 

strategy("ADX daily long", overlay=true,initial_capital=100000, currency='USD', commission_type='strategy.commission,cash_per_order',commission_value=1, default_qty_type=strategy.cash,default_qty_value=100000) 
length = input(title="Length", type=integer, defval=14) 
src = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close) 

// Begin ADX 
adxlen = input(14, title="ADX Smoothing") 
dilen = input(14, title="DI Length") 
adx_threshold = input(title="ADX threshold", type=integer, defval=25) 
hd_period = '1D' 

dirmovdirection(len) => 
up = change(high[1]) 
down = -change(low[1]) 
plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0) 
minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0) 
truerange = rma(tr[1], len) 
plus = fixnan(100 * rma(plusDM, len) / truerange) 
minus = fixnan(100 * rma(minusDM, len) / truerange) 
direction = (plus>minus)?1:0 

dirmov(len) => 
up = change(high[1]) 
down = -change(low[1]) 
plusDM = na(up) ? na : (up > down and up > 0 ? up : 0) 
minusDM = na(down) ? na : (down > up and down > 0 ? down : 0) 
truerange = rma(tr, len) 
plus = fixnan(100 * rma(plusDM, len) / truerange) 
minus = fixnan(100 * rma(minusDM, len) / truerange) 
[plus, minus] 

adx(dilen, adxlen) => 
[plus, minus] = dirmov(dilen) 
sum = plus + minus 
adx = 100 * rma(abs(plus - minus) / (sum == 0 ? 1 : sum), adxlen) 

sig = security(tickerid, hd_period, adx(dilen, adxlen)) 
direction = security(tickerid, hd_period, dirmovdirection(dilen)) 
// plot(sig, color=red, title="ADX") 
// End ADX 

if sig > 25 and direction == 1 
strategy.entry("ADX daily long", strategy.long) 

if (sig< 25 or direction == 0) 
strategy.close("ADX daily long")
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. In most cases and especially in backtesting strategies you should use the default value for the lookahead parameter. Otherwise your bactesting would give you false results.

Secondly, your usage of 'security' function, e.g.

```
sig = security(tickerid, hd_period, adx(dilen, adxlen))
```

is correct. In such a case an 'adx(dilen, adxlen)' function will be executed on a different timeframe (according the value of 'hd_period').

The only thing to mention about 'security' is that it is not suited to request data of a timeframes that are lower than the current chart timeframe.

Thanks!